# Is it possible to have two Schengen visas with overlapping dates?

Tags: visas, tourist-visas, schengen-visas, visa-cancellation

I'm a foreign national working in the USA. I applied for a French tourist visa and was offered a visa from July 30, 2018 to August 30, 2018. Now, due to some schedule changes at work, I have to change my travel plans. I would like to now travel to Spain from August 23, 2018 to September 10, 2018.

In this case, I cannot use my French visa to travel to Spain as my travel dates are not within my French visa dates. Hence, I’ll need a new visa.

Am I eligible to apply for a new visa with Spain? Do I need to cancel my French visa before applying for a Spanish visa as the dates are overlapping?  
Can I apply for a Spanish visa starting August 31, 2018 (One day after my French visa expires)?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused if I should cancel my existing visa or apply for a new one with back to back dates. So I believe this question is not a duplicate.

Comment: Yes you should and if you meet any halfway competent consular Officer at the Spanish embassy, he/she will cancel it.

Answer (score 0):

Apply for a visa from Spain, documenting your entire trip, and explain that you will not be making the trip to France your existing visa was issued for.

The Spanish consulate will most likely revoke the French visa.

However, if they instead decide to issue a new visa with back-to-back validity, that will work just as well for you.

Either option will be valid for your plans, so do not worry about trying to tell the consulate which of them to use.